# Add ToolTipText in Jlist Item(s)

Tags: java, tooltip, jlist

```
public static void populateJList(JList list) {
        ArrayList<String> contents= DataAccess.getContents();
        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String string : contents) {
            listModel.addElement(string);
        }
        preset.setModel(listModel);
}
```

I have this method that populates my JList, is there a way that I can add `toolTipText` of every item in the JList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can override the getToolTipText(..) method of the JList.
2. I believe you can also use a custom renderer which invokes the setToolTipText(...) method.

Comment: If you have a `JContainer` with multiple components as list items, then overriding `getToolTipText()` is better..

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to override `JList`, you can use a `MouseMotionAdapter` to change the tooltip text

```
    jList.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            JList l = (JList)e.getSource();
            ListModel m = l.getModel();
            int index = l.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
            if( index>-1 ) {
                l.setToolTipText(m.getElementAt(index).toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For JDK >= 1.6, a slightly different construction is needed:

```
   loggingList.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // no-op
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            JList l = (JList) e.getSource();
            ListModel m = l.getModel();
            int index = l.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
            if (index > -1) {
                l.setToolTipText(m.getElementAt(index).toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: MouseMotionAdapter is an abstract class that already has no-op methods and exists since JDK 1.1